# Thevenin equivalent mesh equations

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source, thevenin

I came across to this problem that deals with Thevenin equivalent in a first order circuit.But for now forget the first order. My problem is how the mesh analysis equations came to this initial equation : \$v_{T} = 2000 i_{T} + 4000(i_{T}-2 \times 10^{3} v_{\phi})\$.

I understand (if I am correct) that he connects a current source of 1 amp in the terminals A,B. And then he tries  KVL in the left loop and KVL in the right loop.

The part that confuses me is the:\$(i_{T}-2 \times 10^{3} v_{\phi})\$.

What are the two equations that were binded?

I think in the left  loop :

\$-v_{T} +2000i_{t} +2 \times 10^3 v_{\phi}=0 \$.

I think in the right loop :

\$ - 2 \times 10^3 v_{\phi}+4000i_{t} =0 \$.

But how he ended in the equation that I have this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Notice that the current that is flowing through 4kΩ resistors is equal to the \$i_T\$ current minus the current "consumed" by a voltage-controlled current source.  \$I_{4k\Omega} = i_T - 2\times10^{-3}V_{\phi}\$  And \$V_{\phi} = i_T*2000\Omega\$ Do you see it now?

Comment: @G36 still no.i don't get it.

Comment: So what part you did not understand?

Comment: @G36 the part that you said: " current minus the current "consumed" by a voltage-controlled current source. " .Why there is a minus the current there ?

Comment: @G36 It would helped it I had all the equations explained from the KCL or KVL in this example in order to understand it.

Comment: This is nothing more than KCL in action at the node. \$i_t = I_{VCSC} + I_{4k\Omega}\$. How about now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit in question

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBwTvt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To solve it we can write I KVL equation (1)

$$V_T = V_{R_1} + V_{R_2} = I_{R_1}*2k\Omega + I_{R_2}*4k\Omega$$

And the KCL at the node

$$I_{R_1} = I_{vccs} + I_{R_2}$$

And from this we can solve for \$R_2\$ current.

$$I_{R_2} = I_{R_1} - I_{vccs}$$ (2)

And we plug this into the first equation:

$$V_T =  2k\Omega \: I_{R_1} + ( I_{R_1} - I_{vccs} )4k\Omega$$

Also, notice that \$ I_{vccs} = 2mS\:V_{R_1} = 2mS*2k\Omega\:I_{R_1} = 4\:I_{R_1}\$

So we have,

$$V_T = 2k\Omega \: I_{R_1} + ( I_{R_1} - 4I_{R_1})\:4k\Omega$$

$$V_T = 2k\Omega \:I_{R_1} +  4k\Omega\:I_{R_1} - 16k\Omega\:I_{R_1}$$

$$V_T = - 10k\Omega\:I_{R_1}$$
$$\frac{V_T}{I_{R_1}} = - 10k\Omega$$

$$R_{TH} = \frac{V_T}{I_{R_1}} = - 10k\Omega$$

Comment: now I got it.Thank you very much for your clear explanation